# Does my tiling pattern based on regular pentagons have any value?

Tags: geometry, polygons, tiling

I have found a non-periodic tiling pattern using just four shapes, two of which are regular pentagons.

Have I discovered something previously unknown, and does it have any value or significance?

[image: pentagonal tiling pattern]

Comment: I suggest that a better venue for this question would be [The Tiling List] (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tiling).

Comment: [+1] Nice and interesting. Can I ask you the principle of its structure ? (I can share on my side some Matlab codes on certain patterns)

Comment: I found an old file of this and it has taken a few days of research to find out what I was up to. The central patch of a pentagon surrounded by five stars and ten smaller pentagons is by Kepler (1619). It seemed like good progress with the five-fold tiling problem, so I wanted to see how it failed. The next row required the addition of an element with two-fold symmetry. I have added the darker blue shape and considered the two pentagons as overlapping rather than fused. It was exciting to find that further rows could be made by simply adding one more such pair to each side.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your tiles can *also* tile the plane periodically -- that's what happens in each of the five sectors of the plane that meet at the central pentagon.

Non-periodic tilings with tiles that could also tile periodically, are unfortunately not something particularly new and remarkable. (It is simple to construct such an example with $2\times 1$ rectangles, for example).